# How to the domain url in laravel5

Tags: laravel, url, laravel-blade

I have to get the domain url (ex. http://www.example.com/) in laravel blade. I've tried using {{ url() }} but it returns the path to my public directory. Is there any one line function to get this? How do I get the domain in blade? Need help. Thanks.

Comment: you mean now it returns 'var/www/app/public' or 'www.app.com/public' ?

Comment: try `{{ Request::root() }}`

Comment: no i just need 'www.example.com'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also try

`{{ Request::server ("SERVER_NAME") }}
{{ Request::server ("SERVER_NAME") }}`

Or go with

`{{ Request::root() }}`